# Reading HTML form name in Django views

Tags: python, html, django

I want to define a view that should display from which page the request is coming.

for example:

'Request is coming from index page'

'Request is coming from home page'

...................

................ so on

views.py

```
def practice(request):
        return HttpResponse(request.POST)
```

it is displaying all the form fields but I am not able to get the form name.

Html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<h1>Creating Incident</h1>
    <form name = "index" action = 'practice' method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <center>
            <table>
        <tr><td>Support portal username</td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = USERNAME size="50"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your Email</td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = EMAIL size="50"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'password' name = PASSWORD size="50"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Xtreme ID</td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = COMPANYID size="50"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer email </td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = CUSTOMEREMAIL size="50"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Event Note </td><td>:</td><td><textarea id="eventnote" name= EVENTNOTE rows="8" cols="48"></textarea></td></tr>
                </table><br>
            <input type = 'submit' value = 'submit'>     <a href="Home"><input type="button" value="Home"></a>
        </center>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `name` is a legacy attribute for different purpose than getting send with the data. If you need that value, then add a hidden input with it.

Comment: Also Django [includes tools for handling forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) so you should use that instead of creating form manually.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`